What does こちらとしても mean?

（君が）そこまでの無理を強いるのはこちらとしても不本意なんだが！

I'm confused by what こちらとしても means. Here's what I can put together so far. こちら means "this direction" and generally refers one's side or oneself. として, the Te-form of とする, means to enact, or regard something as, whatever is quoted with と. も is the including particle, and can translate into "even", "also", or "too", but will always contain an element of including.
So the most literal translation I can get is "As for forcing the impossibility of (you) going that far, even regarding me, I am unwilling.". A less literal translation, provided by DeepL, would be "I am unwilling to force you to go that far!".
But I'm still stumped by what こちらとしても is doing in this sentence. Can someone please explain what it means, why it's used, and how it can be used in other sentences please.

You'd better think it is として as a word on its own.
The usage in question is the same as the example:

私としては賛成でも反対でもない
As for me, I am neither for nor against it.

Here it is も instead of は, so こちらとしても literally means as for our side, too.
The sentence says "asking that much is not what is wanted on our side too (as well as on your side)".

I'll be honset, your explanation only made it more confusing. It looks like you could completely remove として from your example and it will change nothing. Now it looks like this word could mean "to attempt...", "to regard as...", or just not mean anything at all. Why is it even there? What is it doing? And how is it even any different from just と + する?

@DietSouda It adds something just like as for me adds in the quoted example. It is omittable without changing the meaning much, but it's not nothing. I don't think you can infer the meaning from とする.

While it might help to see として as one word to understand its function, こちらとしましては／も is also possible.
